# How to create alarm when calendar event is created?

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarm

I have inserted an event in a calendar. The time of event created must also be created with alarm of the same time to ring. How to do it? I have used following code and it gives folowing error.

I get following error when i use the following code:
Main Activity:

```
    Calendar caln = Calendar.getInstance();

    caln.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ToDoApplicationActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarm_message", title1);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
    startActivity(intent);
```

OnReceive method overrided:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   try {
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");

     Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, ToDoApplicationActivity.class);
     newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
     newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(newIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     e.printStackTrace();

    }
 }
```

ERROR got:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.todoapplication/android.todoapplication.AlarmReceiver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Any Help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add your activity **"AlarmReceiver"** in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.
If your activity **extends** an Android Receiver (E.g: BroadcastReceiver), Add it like this :

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
  ...

  <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
</application>
```

else

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
  ...

  <activity android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
</application>
```